# Не работает алгоритм сортировки выбором

Tags: python, алгоритм, сортировка

```
def selectionSort(sequence):
    print(sequence)
    min_number = sequence[0]
    index_of_min_num = 0 
    p = 0
    mistakes = 1
    while p != len(sequence)-1 :
        mistakes = 0
        min_number = sequence[p]
        index_of_min_num = p
        for i in sequence[p:]:
            if i < min_number:
                min_number = i
                index_of_min_num = sequence.index(i)
                mistakes += 1

        sequence[index_of_min_num] = sequence[p]
        sequence[p] = min_number
        p += 1

    return sequence

print(selectionSort([81, 84, 57, 20, 49, 18, 9, 13, 96, 49]))
```

Если дать в фу-ю выборку без повторяющихся чисел, то все сортирует нормально, но если есть два одинаковые числа, то их она не сортирует (выносит на конец или еще на какие-то места в массиве).
не могли бы вы объяснить почему такое происходит и как исправить? пожалуйста

Answer (score 2):

Вот рабочий вариант:

```
N = int(input())
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
k = 0

for i in range(N):
    k = i - 1
    num = a[i]

    while a[k] > num and k >= 0:
        a[k + 1], a[k] = a[k], a[k + 1]
        k -= 1

print(*a)
```

Удивительно, но на Википедии алгоритм на питоне неверный, как заметил и объяснил участник @MBo, поэтому вот другой:

```
size = int(input())
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]

for idx_i in range(size - 1):
  min_idx = idx_i

  for idx_j in range(idx_i + 1, size):
    if a[idx_j] < a[min_idx]:
      min_idx = idx_j

  if min_idx != idx_i:
    a[idx_i], a[min_idx] = a[min_idx], a[idx_i]

print(*a)
```

Comment: i - элемент массива

Comment: @кля добавил рабочий код

Comment: Это **не** сортировка выбором, а плоховатые вставки

Comment: @MBo брал отсюда https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сортировка_выбором

Comment: Увы., есть какая-то цитата про то, что большинство кода в инете - г.  На той странице на других языках  сортировка выбором сделана верно, но не на Python

Comment: @MBo расскажите, почему неверно. Без объяснения почему для меня это звучит как ваше мнение против мнения Википедии, сами же понимаете, кому лучше доверять :)

Comment: Там же приведено описание и правильные реализации - выбрать минимум из необработанного хвоста и один раз обменять с первым элементом этого хвоста. А приведённый код последовательно меняет элемент с соседями, пока тот не встанет на место (см. алгоритмы  вставками и пузырьком)

Comment: @MBo да, согласен

Comment: @MBo переписал C++ алгоритм оттуда

Comment: Да, всё верно. .

Answer (score 1):

а откуда вы взяли этот алгоритм ?
в книге грокаем алгоритмы есть вполне рабочий:

```
def findSmallest(arr):
    smallest = arr[0]
    smallest_index = 0
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        if arr[i] < smallest:
            smallest = arr[i]
            smallest_index = i
    return smallest_index

def selectionSort(arr):
    newArr = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        smallest = findSmallest(arr)
        newArr.append(arr.pop(smallest))
    return newArr
print (selectionSort( [81, 84, 57, 20, 9, 49, 18, 9, 13, 96, 49] ))
```

Comment: писал сам по описанию алгоритма, хочу сам додуматься, а не брать рабочий код....

Answer (score 1):

```
def selection(data):
    for i, e in enumerate(data):
        mn = min(range(i, len(data)), key=data.__getitem__)
        data[i], data[mn] = data[mn], e
    return data

print(selection([81, 84, 57, 20, 9, 49, 18, 9, 13, 96, 49]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def selectionSort(sequence):
    start_sequence_len = len(sequence)
    correct_sequence = []
    p = 0

    while p != start_sequence_len:
        min_number = sequence[0]
        index_of_min_num = 0
        for i in sequence:
            if i <= min_number:
                min_number = i
                index_of_min_num = sequence.index(i)

        correct_sequence.append(min_number)
        sequence[index_of_min_num] = sequence[0]
        if p != start_sequence_len:
            del sequence[0]
        p += 1

    return correct_sequence
```

ВСЕ РЕШИЛ, ВСЕМ СПАСИБО ЗА ПОМОЩЬ

Comment: Это код слишком ухудшен по сравнению с обычной сортировкой выбором. Неразумно перебирать значения, а потом искать их индексы, когда можно просто пройти по индексам. Да и танцы с sequence лишние.